# Symfony2 simple contact form on every page

Tags: php, symfony, twig, block

I would like to have a simple contact form in the footer of every page. I already created a controller which is working fine on a seperate page. But when i render the controller inside of a template:

`{%  render(controller('MyBundle:Default:contact', {'request': app.request })) %}`

It is working for rendering the form, validation and sending the mail BUT

1.) my flashmessage is not shown:

`$this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(...)`

and 2.) When i try to redirect i get an error

`return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('homepage'))`

So my question is:

- How can i set the flash message and redirect?
- Is rendering a controller in twig actually the best practice? Or are there other approaches?

(I also tried to create a twig extension but ran into different other problems like i cant use formbuilder function etc...)

Comment: Which symfony2 version are you using and can you show the redirect error message?

Comment: latest version 2.4.0 . For flashbang i dont get an error, its just not shown. For redirect i get: 

```An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template. Error when rendering "http://localhost/name/web/app_dev.php/kontakt" (Status code is 302).") in MyBundle:page:kontakt.html.twig at line 19.```

Answer (score 2):

Method `get` from `FlashBag` apart from getting the message in addition removes it... So probably you've invoked get method somewhere before. For example following code always shows nothing:

```
{% if (app.session.flashbag.get('message')) %}
    <div class="message">{{ app.session.flashbag.get('message') }}</div>
{% endif %}
```

If this is the case, then instead of the first `get` you should use `has` method in the condition.

Moreove if you want get and only get the message from the flash bag - without removing it, you can use `peek` method.